# Groupset Change

Tags: groupsets

Hi I am new to cycling and thinking to change my groupset Ultegra to either 6870 di2 or Dura ace 9000 can get either for around the same sort of outlay I only cycle for fun and exercise can some one give me any ideas or preference for either item bike is 2015 Dogma think 2 Thanks

Comment: Seems like a troll question, given "new to cycling" and a Pinarello and Ultegra.

Comment: Those are very high-end components – if you don't know which you need, are you sure you're going to benefit from them?  It seems more sensible to stick with cheaper components until you know exactly what your needs are.

Comment: How many hours per day do you ride?   How far?  Mostly flat or a lot of climbs?  Your options are both top-end parts, both will work exceptionally well for top level racing, and will probably vanish in a heartbeat if you left the bike locked up in a public rack.   Please add further info, else the question will be closed as "too broad" or "opinion based"  This will also indicate whether your question is specious.

Comment: It is quite a high-spec bike. Very nice. It'll be great fun, but you're probably gonna get it nicked unless you buy a reeaaallllyyy good lock, too. Get a cheaper, cable-actuated groupset and used the cash saved to buy a few bloody good locks; you're gonna need them! (from personal experience, I caught them trying to break my lock!)

For those saying that because he's a "new biker" and talking about Pinarello and Ultegra, doesn't mean he could possibly be trolling; I started out on the same spec bike Martyn Ashton used for Road Bike Party 2, a Colnago C59 hydraulic disc with DI2 Dura Ace.

Comment: Yes, anyone who has been riding for a while should know that only Super Record will do and Ultegra or Dura Ace is just wasting the money. But hey, newbie tax :)

Answer (score 0):

DI2 is an electronic shifter. This is not really necessary for fun or exercise, a good old cable groupset will do. I always use old shifter sets that work simply because I don't race. I'd buy something cheaper than the Dura-Ace 9k, I'd go for Shimano 105, I personally find they feel exactly the same other than really slight mechanical habits such as feeling slightly looser than the Dura-Ace, but that's negligible compared to the price and the value out of it.

If anything, stick with a cheaper groupset, you won't need the other fancier ones.

Comment: If you have ultegra, why would you downgrade?

Comment: Because everyone know that previous year's stuff is just obsolete. Better to scrap the frame, too.

Comment: Why would you waste an Ultegra on just excercise when a cable-actuated 105 feels exactly the same, less of a price and has only negligible differences? Or are you a brand-name elitist, Batman?

Comment: @yollooool No, he was pointing out that the OP said he already owned an ultegra groupset. Why would you pay money at all to buy lesser components than you already have? Please keep your comments civil and directly related to the question asked.

Comment: Been away for a few weeks...

I already knew that he already had that (as implied) but he can sell that, buy the 105 and then put that money towards something else (wider tyres, replacement cables (inner and outer) and/or just getting the bike serviced)